# Java : Generics, wildcards with multiple bounds

Tags: java, bounded-wildcard, unbounded-wildcard

First of all, happy new year to everyone !
I would like to write a method with a multiple bounds parameter like that:

```
public static void max(List<? extends Number & Comparable<?>> list)
```

But unfortunately this code does not compile, could someone explain to me why writing a wilcard parameter with multiple bounds is not possible ?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible because it's not defined as part of the language, just like the other infinitely many things which are not possible because they are not part of the language.

Comment: That isn't a useful wildcard anyway; you need the "comparable to" to be the same as the kind of thing in the list.

Comment: You probably want a type parameter `T extends Number & Comparable<? super T>` and make a `List<T>`.